# SeekBar block tapping when previous event is not moving

Tags: android, android-widget, android-seekbar

I wrote a solution for it, it's working perfect but i think that is not the best solution...

```
private volatile boolean sweepEvent;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


    if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction() && !sweepEvent) {
        sweepEvent = false;
        ((View) this.getParent()).performClick();
        return false;
    } else if (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE == event.getAction()) {
        sweepEvent = true;
    } else {
        sweepEvent = false;
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

As you can see i also need call parent view (LinearLayout) when user tapping on seekbar but not moving progress. line :  **((View) this.getParent()).performClick();** but its not working at all ...

I am thinking to add a new listener for a callback but iti s not a good solution ...

Comment: and what is your intention? what do you actually want to do?

Comment: first it is good solution ?
second how send click event (ACTION UP) to the parent ?,(children is a list item)

Comment: its not clear what you want to do...

Comment: I have got list and one of it element is seekbar. When i click on seek bar but not change progress i must send that event and call onListItemCLick. So my seek bar can not change progress when user simpcy click on it, but only when user sweep progressbar.

Comment: use setOnSeekBarChangeListener and add logging (Log.d) in every method of the listener, it should be clear what to do next